# Can someone please explain the Link List Code Below

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Sorry if this is a dumb question but for the code below I can't understand why new_node.next = head_ref. So this would mean the pointer for the new_node.next is for "a" and not the pointer for the next node, which I was expecting. Then it creates another node and sets its new_node.next to the previous node's memory location.

Sorry if this does not make sense but what I'm trying to figure out is for the first node where is the pointer for the second node and so fourth. I think it's the use of head_ref that is confusing me. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
# Python implementation of above
# algorithm
# Node class
class Node:

    # Constructor to initialize the
    # node object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None




# Utility Functions
# Function to print linked list
def printList(head):
    temp = head
    while (temp != None):
        print(temp.data, end=" ")
        temp = temp.next


# A utility function to insert a node
# at the beginning of linked list
def push(head_ref, new_data):
    # Allocate node
    new_node = Node(0)

    # Put in the data
    new_node.data = new_data

    # Link the old list off the
    # new node
    new_node.next = head_ref


    # Move the head to point to
    # the new node
    head_ref = new_node
    return head_ref


# Driver code
a = None

a = push(a, 5)
a = push(a, 20)
a = push(a, 4)
a = push(a, 3)
a = push(a, 30)

print("Linked List before sorting  ")
printList(a)
```

Comment: `push` is, in some sense, overly complicated. `new_node = Node(new_data); new_node.next = head_ref; return new_node`. Create a new node, have it point to the old head, return it as the new head: done.

Comment: `a` is constantly updated; it's only the correct argument for each call to `push` because it gets set to the return value of the *previous* call. You could also write `a = push(push(push(push(push(None, 5), 20), 4), 3), 30)`.

Answer (score 0):

When a new node is appended, its `next` value is set to the previous `head`, because the node is being added to the beginning of the linked list. Because there is now a new node at the head of the linked list, it **becomes the head**. Keep in mind that `head` just refers to the first node in the linked list.

Example:

Let's start with a LinkedList, denoted as a Python list, with contents [0].

Our list:

```
[0]
```

After `push(val)`:

We get:

```
val.next = 0 # because 0 was previously at the front
head = val # because val is now at the front
```

Our list:

```
[val, 0]
```

This logic will occur after each `push()` call.

**Note: The 'other values' do not disappear.**

If our list became something like this:

```
[head, val, 0]
```

A quick way to access the third element of the LinkedList (which would be index 2 in a normal list), would be to call `head.next.next`.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to visualise what happens at every call of `push`. So we start in the main part with a name `a` that is `None`:

```
a=None
```

### First node

Then we call `push(a, 5)`, which in that function means that `head_ref` is `None` and `new_data` is 5. Then `new_node` is created as a `Node` instance and `new_data` becomes its data. We get this state:

```
 head_ref:None

 new_node
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 5    │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
```

Now the assignment `new_node.next = head_ref` has no effect, since that `next` attribute was already `None`. Then  `head_ref` gets the same reference as `new_node`:

```
 head_ref
 new_node
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 5    │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
```

This `head_ref` is also the return value of the function, and in the main program, this returned value is assigned to `a`. The function's names (like `new_node` are now out of scope:

```
  a
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 5    │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
```

### Second node

The second call is `push(a, 20)`. In that function a `new_node` is created with as value 20:

```
                    head_ref
 new_node            a
  │                  │
  ▼                  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: None │     │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

At this moment that new node is not yet part of the linked list. That is about to change with the assignment `new_node.next = head_ref`:

```
                    head_ref
 new_node            a
  │                  │
  ▼                  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

So now `new_node` is the first node of a linked list with two nodes. Now we assign the reference to that first node to `head_ref`:

```
 head_ref
 new_node            a
  │                  │
  ▼                  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

This same reference (to the first node) is returned to the main program, where that reference is assigned to the name `a` (which was still referencing the node with value 5). So in the main program we get:

```
  a
  │
  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

### Third node

Let's do one more call: `push(a, 4)`. The `new_node` gets created with value 4:

```
                     head_ref
 new_node            a
  │                  │
  ▼                  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 4    │     │ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: None │     │ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

Again, we link up that new node with `new_node.next = head_ref`:

```
                     head_ref
 new_node            a
  │                  │
  ▼                  ▼ 
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 4    │     │ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: ─────────► │ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

Then again `head_ref` is adjusted to reference that node, and that reference is returned to the calling program where it overwrites the old reference that name `a` had:

```
  a
  │
  ▼
┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐     ┌────────────┐ 
│ data: 4    │     │ data: 20   │     │ data: 5    │
│ next: ─────────► │ next: ─────────► │ next: None │
└────────────┘     └────────────┘     └────────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies the process.